# Adjusting the floating elements on a webpage

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
                                              Email               Password
                                              [Email box]         [Password Box] [Log In]
                                              []keep me logged in Forgot Password?
```

I've been successful in implementing the first two lines (Email ... [Log In]) but can't shape the last line.
Here's the code.

```
<ul>
<li>
<label for="mail">Email: </label><br>
<input type="email" name="mail" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" />
    <small>Keep me signed in</small>
</li>
<li>
<label for="paswrd">Password: </label><br>
<input type="password" name="paswrd" /><br>
<small>Forgot  Password?</small>
</li>
<li><button type="button" name="login">Log In</button></li><br><p> </p>
</ul>
```

The CSS code is as follows.

```
header ul {float: right;}
    header ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #FFEBCD;
        font-family: "Maiandra GD";
    }
header small {float: right;}
```

Comment: Looks like you've already received the answer you were after.  One thing I noticed though, is that you are using the "for" attribute for your label tags, but they're virtually useless.  The "for" attribute points to an element's id, not its name.
To get the most out of your code, add id's to your inputs that reflect the same name you're using with the respective "for"s and you'll be good to go.
Src:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Comment: I read about "for" as new addition to HTML5 and that it helps you relate to your input. But I didn't know about how actually does it do that. Your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this with two div's one float to the left the second float to the right

see an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5dygq/)

```
<div class="left_div">
   <label for="mail">Email: </label><br>
   <input type="email" name="mail" /><br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" />
    <small>Keep me signed in</small>
</div>
<div class="right_div">
  <label for="paswrd">Password: </label><br>
  <input type="password" name="paswrd" /><br>
  <small>Forgot  Password?</small>
</div>
```

The CSS code

```
.left_div {
   float: left;
   width: 300px;    
 }

.right_div {
   float: right;
   width: 300px;    
 }
```